# doctrine:migrations:diff give "No changes detected in your mapping information"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using doctrine in combination with symfony. For the database setup I'm using annotations. I created a table successfully but gave the wrong format `integer` for a field `city` which I need to change to `string`. My understanding was, that when I'm changing the annotations in the customers class from

```
class Customer{

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
   * @var string city
   */
  private $city;

}
```

to

```
class Customer{

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
   * @var string city
   */
  private $city;

}
```

and then run

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

all changes of the mapping should be recognized and a php file should be generated containing an ALTER TABLE query or similar. However, this command replies with a **"No changes detected in your mapping information"**. What am I missing?

Comment: @ORM\Column(type="string")

Comment: type string is default. However, I tried your suggestion but the behavior remains the same.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I needed to first clear the cache with

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Success!

Answer (score 8):

You should add the annotation `@Entity` to the entity to be recognized as an entity in doctrine ORM.

```
<?php

/**
 * Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourBundle/Repository/YourRepositoryName")
 */
class Customer{

       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
        * @var string city
        */
        private $city;

}
```

You can also use this command to auto-generate entities with different required annotations:

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

Comment: Sorry, I failed to give the full code. Of course there is the Entity annotation in my code.

Answer (score 5):

This can also happened when your mapping is invalid.

A quick workaround would be to do

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

Then fix errors until you see

`[OK] The mapping files are correct.`

Now make `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` again and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to add the --from-empty-schema flag.

```
doctrine:migrations:diff --from-empty-schema
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @agoldev I needed to clear the cache. Just not the doctrine metadata cache but the symfony cache. But he lead me to find this solution.

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had mapping type 'attribute' in doctrine config file, but entity had annotations.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a complicated Symfony configuration check `doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.mappings` config values in `config.yml`. Probably you have to add your new bundle here when it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

In case it can help others, for me it was just a matter of a wrong namespace set in my entity class.

I had duplicated an entity from another package and forgot to update the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had placed my entity in bundle Doctrine folder but had to place it into Entity folder.